# Merge the rows in dataframe with first row priority and update sequence from second row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input dataframe with the start and end index which needs updation,

## Input Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
        'id': [0,1,2,3],
        'start': [109,119,163,169],
        'end': [118,123,168,173],
        'tag': ['NN','NN','NN','NN'],
        'pos':['N','V','N','N'],
        'words':['Toe','pain','Knee','pain'],
        'MergedOutput':['B-DISEASE','I-DISEASE','B-DISEASE','I-DISEASE',],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

## Input dataframe as displayed below

```
df
Out[2]: 
   id  start  end tag pos words MergedOutput
0   0    109  118  NN   N   Toe    B-DISEASE
1   1    119  123  NN   V  pain    I-DISEASE
2   2    163  168  NN   N   Knee    B-DISEASE
3   3    169  173  NN   N  pain    I-DISEASE
```

## Output Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data_target = {
        'id': [0,2,],
        'start': [109,163],
        'end': [123,173],
        'tag': ['NN','NN'],
        'pos':['N','N'],
        'words':['Toe pain','Knee pain'],
        'MergedOutput':['B-DISEASE','B-DISEASE'],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_target)
```

## Required Dataframe as shown below,

```
df
Out[5]: 
   id  start  end tag pos      words MergedOutput
0   0    109  123  NN   N   Toe pain    B-DISEASE
1   2    163  173  NN   N  Knee pain    B-DISEASE
```

Thanking you added my required dataframe Need to update the end index and the merged out put class as B-Disease. when ever the B-Disease and I-Disease appear together and consecutive.

Comment: and what should happen in case of 2 `I-Disease`? or other items?

Comment: please change that to Knee, Please edit for Toe pain and Knee pain

Comment: The words has to be combined from the second row to  the first row, and the index from the second row should be updated for the first row and the merged output label remains the same of the first row.

Comment: Do your start and end tags have anything to due with groupying, can I check to see if end + 1 equals to the start of the next record, if not then this is not part the same group?

Comment: @jezrael please answer this question

Comment: @ScottBoston, No Start and end text need not be considered the end  of second becomes the end of first row after combining, the only condition is the B-Disease and I-Disease should come one after the next. or you can ignore grouping for now as we can handle this by filter for the merged output column

Comment: @vinsent I am confused, are you the same person as OP?

Comment: @mozway LOL Me too.

Comment: @mozway  in case of two  I-Disease in the subsequent rows, we need to combine three rows to 1 single row as B-Disease and the start index will be from the first and the end index will be from the 3rd row Thanking you for that thought process

Comment: @mozway Iam Neelam's workmate

Comment: OK, then @Scott's first solution should work for you

Answer (score 3):

Try this using cumsum on B-DISEASE:

```
g = (df['MergedOutput'] == "B-DISEASE").cumsum()

print(df.groupby(g, as_index=False).agg(id=('id','first'),
                  start=('start','first'),
                  end=('end', 'last'),
                  tag=('tag', 'first'),
                  pos=('pos', 'first'),
                  words=('words'," ".join),
                  MergedOutput=('MergedOutput', 'first')))
```

Output:

```
   id  start  end tag pos      words MergedOutput
0   0    109  123  NN   N   Toe pain    B-DISEASE
1   2    163  173  NN   N  Knee pain    B-DISEASE
```

---

Here's one-way using the start and end to define groups:

```
g = (df['end'] + 1 == df['start'].shift(-1)).cumsum()

df.groupby(g).agg(id=('id','first'),
                  start=('start','first'),
                  end=('end', 'last'),
                  tag=('tag', 'first'),
                  pos=('pos', 'first'),
                  words=('words'," ".join),
                  MergedOutput=('MergedOutput', 'first'))
```

Output:

```
   id  start  end tag pos      words MergedOutput
1   0    109  123  NN   N   Toe pain    B-DISEASE
2   2    163  173  NN   N  Knee pain    B-DISEASE
```

Comment: Note that as you don't change the column names, you can directly use `agg({'id': 'first', 'start': 'first', ...})` ;) +1

Comment: @mozway... yeah.... I am rusty with my solutions these days.